# non-root url not working when directly entered in browser address bar for ember app deployed in Jetty

Tags: ember.js, jetty

I have a simple app developed using Ember. It is more of a pet project than anything else. As I am familiar with Jetty, so I just deployed it into Jetty's webapps/ROOT. The problem is, I have to start the app with the root url: http://localhost:8080/. If I enter something like http://localhost:8080/foobar in browser's address bar, I will get a 404. But I can go to that page by clicking some link in the root page.

To my understanding, the reason why directly entering the non-root foobar url not working is that Jetty is trying to locate the foobar resource. Since the foobar resource is only resolvable inside the Ember app, Jetty can't find it and hence it fails to enter non-root url directly. However, my question is, how can I make that directly entered url work? If it can not be done or not easily be done with Jetty, I am open to use another http server.

Comment: You can also just use `location:'hash'`

Comment: Kingpin2k, can you elaborate with examples, please?

Comment: documentation: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html, example: http://output.jsbin.com/huzubavice